# Trying to get textbox input and output working

Tags: javascript, html

The core js function and console output works when the nText var is set manually (`var nText = "exampleText"` for instance) but I'm trying to make it take textbox input, perform the function, and then spit the result back out into the same textbox but I'm stuck on getting that to work. Any help with this would be appreciated, I'm still fairly new to js and this is just a little personal project I'm trying to do for practice.

```js
function firstLetterUppercase(input = 'nText') {
  var res = "";
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    res += i % 2 == 0 ? input.charAt(i).toUpperCase() : input.charAt(i);
  }
  return res;
}

var nText = document.getElementById("nText").value;

console.log(firstLetterUppercase(nText));
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="nText">Your Text:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nText" name="nText"><br><br>
  <button onclick="firstLetterUppercase (input = 'nText')">aLtErNaTe</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lil modifications you will need to make, just try the below code and see if that helps

```html
<form>
<label for="nText">Your Text:</label>
<input type="text" id="nText" name="nText"><br><br>
<button onclick="firstLetterUppercase()">aLtErNaTe</button>
</form>
<script>
    
function firstLetterUppercase () {
var input = document.getElementById("nText").value
  var res = "";
  for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
     res += i % 2 == 0 ? input.charAt(i).toUpperCase() : input.charAt(i);
  }
   document.getElementById("nText").value =  res;  
}

</script>
```

Comment: You should prevent default to stop the page from being redirected and that should do the trick

Comment: add e.preventDefault into firstLetterUppercase function to prevent page reload.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer and the comments got me on track and it's working great now

Answer (score 0):

There are many updates required in your code.

1. Passing param was incorrect in html `onclick="firstLetterUppercase (input = 'nText')"`
2. Button type should be button, to avoid submitting the form,
3. In console you were passing the empty string to the function which will not be overridden by `input = "nText"` because `empty string != null`
4. No need to use `charAt(i)`, when you can use index.
5. While passing the parameter including some capital letters, you'll need to convert them to `toLowerCase` as well
6. On click you are not printing the result in console.

```js
function firstLetterUppercase(input, print) { // added flag print
  input = (input == "") ? "nText" : input; // if input is empty string
  var res = "";
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    res += (i % 2 == 0) ? input[i].toUpperCase() : input[i].toLowerCase(); // converted capital letters to lower case
  }

  // to print if the flag asked to print value
  // else return the value to the caller
  
  if (print == 1) console.log(res, "(button clicked)")
  else return res;

}
var nText = document.getElementById("nText").value;

console.log(firstLetterUppercase(nText));
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="nText">Your Text:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nText" name="nText"><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="firstLetterUppercase('nText', 1)">aLtErNaTe</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick is in setting `document.getElementById("nText").value` after you've manipulated it.

```js
//  a DOM reference to make it easy to get and set the value
const nTextField = document.getElementById('nText');

//  button handler
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', ev => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  const nText = nTextField.value
  const massagedText = firstLetterUppercase(nText);
  // Set the text field value
  nTextField.value = massagedText;
});

//  text manipulation
const firstLetterUppercase = (input) => {
  var res = "";
  for (i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
     res += i % 2 == 0 ? input.charAt(i).toUpperCase() : input.charAt(i);
  }
  return res;  
}
```

```html
<form id="f">
  <label for="nText">Your Text:</label>
  <input type="text" id="nText" name="nText"><br><br>
  <button type="button" id="b">aLtErNaTe</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are few issues listed below.

1. Invalid argument to function `onclick="firstLetterUppercase (input = 'nText')"` in html.
2. trying to get the value of input on javascript load rather then click. `var nText = document.getElementById("nText").value;`
3. calling the function again even though it has been called in `onclick` `console.log(firstLetterUppercase(nText));`

My Issue..

Why the form disappear when onsubmit is clicked?

```js
function firstLetterUppercase () {
  var nText = document.getElementById("nText").value;

  var res = "";
  for (let i=0; i < nText.length; i++) {
     res += i % 2 == 0 ? nText.charAt(i).toUpperCase() : nText.charAt(i);
  }
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = res;
  
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="firstLetterUppercase()">
<label for="nText">Your Text:</label>
<input type="text" id="nText" name="nText"><br><br>
<button type="submit">aLtErNaTe</button>
<div id="name"></div>
</form>
```